# Carousel with displaying item data

Tags: jquery, html, slider, carousel, frontend

Does exists a possibility to show slider with a showing some of each item data (like name) on the left and another data of active item (like photo) on the right?

[Screenshot is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tieLI.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: well you can use div inside div and slide the main div